# Hybridization of an Indo-Aryan ethnic group and a Tibeto-Burmese ethnic group

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, population-genetics, anthropology, demography

The state in which I reside houses these two distinct ethnic groups.

**Physical Traits of the Indo-Aryan group**

*Height*:Medium

*Eyes*:does not posses epicanthic fold

*Nasal bones*:is not flat and broad

*skin color*:significant minority has fair complexion

*faces*:round shaped and small,but not flat.

*body hair*:abundant

*cheekbones*: not protruding

Thus the appear  as a south Asian version Caucasoid.

**Physical Traits of the Tibeto-Burmese group**

*Height*:Medium

*Eyes*:possess epicanthic fold

*Nasal bones*:is  flat and broad

*skin color*:significant minority has dark complexion

*faces*:round shaped and small,but flat.

*body hair*: not abundant

*cheekbones*:protruding

Thus the appear  as a south Asian version of Mongoloid.

Since the Indo-Aryan group has migrated recently,there is unavailability significant hybridized population.And I am interested in knowing how the offspring of inter-ethnic mating would physically look like.

But I have failed to apply laws of genetics here as I do not know which are dominant traits?

So,my question is **What would be the physical traits of a 1st generation hybrid offspring  according to law of genetics?**

Comment: You are looking at multi different traits of which at least a few are multigenic in their occurance. This is not like breading beans and simple (even Mendel had quite some amount of luck...).

Comment: Which of these traits are multigenic?

Comment: Eye and skin color for example.

Comment: They are most likely all multigenic, but many may segregate together, leading to the appearance of a monogenic trait. Given enough time, though, they will all blend together.